# IIS JavaScript files give 500 response, served as type "text/html"

Tags: javascript, .net, iis, vbscript

My application has several javascript imports which work without issue, one does not. All js files were served as "text/html"

```
<script src="app/node_modules/lodash/index.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

The file works fine locally (VS2010) but not when deployed to the IIS server.  It fails in both IE11 and Chrome with a 500 error.

```
Microsoft VBScript compilation  error '800a0400' 

Expected statement
app/node_modules/lodash/index.js, line 88 

-([\s\S]+?)
^
```

I have seen similar issues with UnderscoreJs as well.

Comment: All JavaScript files are type text/html. Mime Maps already have .js set as application/javascript, but it doesn't appear to affect anything.

Comment: In IIS6 I found that there was an application extension for *.js. Removing it caused the Mime Map to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following fixes removed the MIME bypasses and allowed them to be set correctly.

In IIS6: Remove application extension for .js

IIS7: Remove handler mapping for .js